# jQuery events don't work when html is injected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
function SetTableBehavior() {
    $(".displayData tr").hover(function(e) {
        $(this).children().addClass('displayDataMouseOver');
    }, function () {
        $(this).children().removeClass('displayDataMouseOver');
    });
    $(".displayData tr td").click(function(e) {
        var rowsSel = $(".displayData .displayDataRowSelected");
        for (var i = 0; i < rowsSel.length; i++) {
            var rowSel = rowsSel[i];
            $(rowSel).children().removeClass("displayDataRowSelected");
        }
        $(this).parent().addClass('displayDataRowSelected');
        var p = $(this).parent();
        p.children().addClass('displayDataRowSelected');
    });
}
```

When the body of the table is injected neither hover or click work.
If i use

```
$(".displayData tr td").live('click',function(e) {
```

the click event works but

```
$(".displayData tr").live('hover',function(e) {
```

doesn't work

What is the solution so that hover works.
Thanks.

It seems to work like this:

```
function SetTableBehavior() {
    $(".displayData tr").live('mouseenter', function (e) {
        $(this).children().addClass('displayDataMouseOver');
    }).live('mouseleave', function(e) {
        $(this).children().removeClass('displayDataMouseOver');
    });
    $(".displayData tr td").live('click',function(e) {
        var rowsSel = $(".displayData .displayDataRowSelected");
        for (var i = 0; i < rowsSel.length; i++) {
            var rowSel = rowsSel[i];
            $(rowSel).children().removeClass("displayDataRowSelected");
        }
        $(this).parent().addClass('displayDataRowSelected');
        var p = $(this).parent();
        p.children().addClass('displayDataRowSelected');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(".hoverme").live("mouseover mouseout", function(event) {
  if ( event.type == "mouseover" ) {
    // do something on mouseover
  } else {
    // do something on mouseout
  }
});
```

From here: http://api.jquery.com/live/

There is no event called "hover" so you can't use it with live or bind.  It is just a "short-cut" that jQuery implemented for us.

Comment: `hover()` implements the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, not `mouseover` and `mouseout`

Comment: Did I say one way or another?  This is simply a copy-paste from the jQuery doc that I linked to.

Comment: Well, the question is asking how to make **hover** work for injected HTML elements... and replacing `hover` with a `mouseover` and `mouseout` call is not a replacement.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use hover with `live`. You'll have to split it up in 2 separate event listeners: one for [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/), and another one for [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/).

Additionally, in your situation, you don't need `live`. Use `delegate`, which is much better for performance:

```
$(".displayData").delegate('tr', 'mouseeneter',function(e) {
    $(this).children().addClass('displayDataMouseOver');
})
.delegate('tr', 'mouseleave',function(e) {
    $(this).children().removeClass('displayDataMouseOver');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`hover(a, b)` is a shortcut for `mouseenter(a).mouseleave(b)` (which themselves, are shortcuts for `bind('mouseenter', a).bind('mouseleave', b)`), so try:

```
$(".displayData tr").live('mouseenter', function(e) { 
    // mouseenter handler
}).live('mouseleave', function (e) {
    // mouseleave handler    
});
```

For more info, see the [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover) and [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) docs.